# Calculating the moment of inertia with respect to z-axis (volume integral)

Tags: vector-analysis

Question states: 
Consider a body with a surface defined by $2(x^{2}+y^{2})+4z^{2}=1$. Calculate the moment of inertia with respect to the z-axis, i.e. 
$I_{z}=\int\int\int_{V}(x^{2}+y^{2})dxdydz$.

I applied the generalized spherical coordinates: 
**s**=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r\cos(\psi) \sin(\theta)$ **i** +$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r\sin(\psi) \sin(\theta)$ **j** +$\frac{1}{2}r\cos(\theta)$ **k**.

What are the boundaries of r, $\theta$ and $\psi$ in that case?

The volume integral than states:
$I_{z}=\int\int\int_{V}(r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta))\  dr\  d\theta \ d\psi$.

So, the rest to do is to calculate the triple integral with adequate boundaries?

Comment: 1: Your body is a surface, not a volume. Or add a Dirac function. 2 : Note that for every slice z, it's a circle...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By Divergence Theorem $$\int_{V}\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}=\int_{\partial V}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$$. Now you can consider the vector field $\mathbf{F}=(x^3/3+y^2x,0,0)$. At this point we have $$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}=x^2+y^2,$$ hence your moment of inertia is $$I_z=\int_{\partial V}(x^3/3+y^2x,0,0)\cdot d\mathbf{S}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The body is an ellipsoid $2x^2+2y^2+4z^2=1$ where the $z$-axis is an axis of rotational symmetry.
Using cylinder coordinates $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$, $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and Jacobian $r$ the integral is
$$
I_z=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} dz \int_{2(x^2+y^2)\le 1-4z^2} r dr  \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r^2
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} dz \int_0^{\sqrt{(1-4z^2)/2}} r^3 dr
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} dz \frac{1}{64}(2-8z^2)^2
$$
$$
=\pi/15 .
$$